# How to get/interact with element_locator on the internal page in chromium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am building automation for the browser (from chromium kernel)
while locating element from some internal page such as: chrome://settings/

I can get xpath of "Autofill" by //*[@id="autofill"]
But when I run the script by Robot framework, it said "Element with locator '//*[@id="autofill"]' not found."
Here is the simple script:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Open URL in Google Chrome
    Open browser    chrome://settings/  chrome
    Click Element   //*[@id="autofill"]


*** Keywords ***
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFSQn.jpg

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: That element is in shadow dom. Google "selenium shadow dom" for a solution.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much!